# How to store streaming data in cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, analytics

I am new in Cassandra, I am very confused.I know that cassandra write speed is very fast.I want to store twitter data coming from storm.I googled, Every time I got make sstable and load into cluster. If every time I have to make sstable then how it possible to store twitter data streaming in cassandra.

please help me.

How I can store log data, which is generated at 1000log per second.

please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Please be more descriptive. do u want to bulk load data or stream data continously in cassandra

Answer (score -1):

I think Cassandra single node can handle 1000 logs per second without bulk loading if your schema is good. Also depends on the size of each log.

Or you could use Cassandra's  `Copy From CSV` command.

For this you need to create a table first.

Here's an example from datastax website :

```
CREATE TABLE airplanes (
  name text PRIMARY KEY,
  manufacturer text,
  year int,
  mach float
);

COPY airplanes (name, manufacturer, year, mach) FROM 'temp.csv';
```

You need to specify the names of the columns based on the order in which they will be stored in the CSV. And for values with comma(,) you could enclose them in double quotes (") or use a different delimiter.

For more details refer http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html

Comment: data is coming 1000log per sec, how it is possible to copy with given command as my data is not in csv. I want to store direct in  cassnadra.

Comment: You need to specify how the data is being streamed. U could easily use datastax cql connector to push data.